# Is it allowed to put the google recaptcha replacement at the bottom with the footer when we hide the badge?

Tags: javascript, recaptcha

I am developing a project and I would like to hide the recaptcha badge from google. According to what they say in the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/faq#id-like-to-hide-the-recaptcha-badge.-what-is-allowed) they mention "You are allowed to hide the badge as long as you include the reCAPTCHA branding visibly in the user flow. Please include the following text":

```
This site is protected by reCAPTCHA and the Google
    <a href="https://policies.google.com/privacy">Privacy Policy</a> and
    <a href="https://policies.google.com/terms">Terms of Service</a> apply.
```

My question is if this code can be placed with the footer at the bottom of the page. Does that fall under this rule?

I want to hide the recaptcha badge without breaking their rules.

Comment: It seems pretty explicit that if you hide the badge you have to include the indicated HTML on any pages that the library. Not really sure what the question is beyond this.